# Welsh-Powell coloring algorithm is better in most cases, or all cases?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I have checked past results (including the original paper from Welsh-Powell), and other sources by googling, and saw that the ordering of the vertices based on descending degrees is not needed for the proof of

$$\chi(G)\leq 1+\max_{i} \min (d(v_i),i-1)$$

One explanation can be found in the answer of this: [Proof of $\chi(G)\leq 1+\max_i\min\{d_i,i-1\}$ in graph theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235182/proof-of-chig-leq-1-max-i-min-d-i-i-1-in-graph-theory)

Basically, we order according to descending degrees because it has good chance of minimizing the max min expression.

My question is: Is that mathematically always true? I can see why it is a good choice of ordering.
Or there is no such proof, and that's why it is called heuristics?

Basically, I want to consider any two orderings of the vertices, one of them is the descending degree ordering, and compare the max min value. However, I cannot seem to prove the descending degree ordering always gives the best result.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Connected and available on the web : "Sequential Coloring versus Welsh-Powell
Bound" by Maciej M. SYSLO

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh my, I did not click on that one thinking it was not what I was looking for. While it gives me no proof (more like left as exercise lol), it indeed helps me confirm it. After trying it out, what is needed is the exchange argument, and gradually applying it until we reach the descending degree ordering. Thanks!!